# Page in Experience Editor hangs forever with page unresponsive dialogs

Tags: experience-editor, javascript, recaptcha

We are using Sitecore 8.2. We have a page with Marketo Form which contains Google Recaptcha. We lazyload the scripts and styles on the page. In experience editor, once we scroll down to the form, the page cannot be edited and does not respond followed by Page Unresponsive dialogs. If we dont scroll down till the form, the page does not hang. The page works fine in normal mode. There are no errors in logs. The only error in browser console is related to recaptcha (snapshot attached). Sitecore had a bug 92994 which had similar symptoms but we are already using higher version which has fix for it.
Anyone had similar issues? Appreciate any pointers!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

do not load google recaptcha script if it is experience editor

you can check if you are in experience editor mode using

```
@Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor
```

this should fix the issue